# How to use onload properties in .ascx file

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript that I needed to execute in an .ascx, I have no access to the .aspx file, since it is generated by Sitecore CMS. so, we have a sublayout .ascx ... i have added my javascript and it works great, there is one small issue though ... I was testing on a shell .aspx page and I was utilizing the following code to only run the javascript after a set amount of time, question... how do I perform the same functionality in .ascx? thank you in advance for your assistance.

```
<body onload="javascript:setTimeout('showModal()', 6000)">
```

Comment: Don't pass a string to `setTimeout`.

Comment: thank you for your response, but I am not clear on the syntax?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp though not the official documentation - very useful.  it's unclear whether you can specify a string or not.  try both. if it works without, then you're golden

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel: It should be `setTimeout(showModal, 6000);`.  You *can* pass a string, but it's bad practice.  Passing a string makes it use `eval`!

Comment: @sircapsalot: If you *do* use the "official" docs, it's very clear.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Comment: @RocketHazmat odd - i'd expect official documentation to come from Oracle seems as they own the trademark :P

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question correctly. I believe what your looking for is `Page.RegisterStartupScript` which will push script into the response and execute it on the page. Simply put your timeout to `showModal()` in the script.

For more information see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Jay fo the response and the article.